# How do I make my program repeat according to certain circumstances?

Tags: java, loops, repeat

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFirstGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Enter A Number: ");
        double s = scanner.nextDouble();
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        double realNumber = randomNumber*10;
        double realerNumber = Math.round(realNumber);
        System.out.println(realerNumber);

        if(s==realerNumber) {
            System.out.println("You Win!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try Again...");
        }
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is make a "game" for my Java class. I have generate a random number between 1 and 10 and the user has to input a number and if the input and the random number are the same, they "win." If they lose, they try again...? First, I did all the necessary scanner stuff that I don't even fully understand. I just copied the professor. So the program says to enter a number and the program generates a number between 0.0 and 1.0. I multiply that number by 10 to make it between 1 and 10. Then I round the number to the nearest integer. If the input matches this number, the program says you win. If not, it'll say try again.

The problem is how do I make the program repeat itself without the user having to reboot the program with the cmd? I need to repeat the input, random number generator, and then the result. What do I need to do? Also, how is my program? My second big one...yeah right...big. But seriously, how can I make it less complex or anything to improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop:

```
long realerNumber = Math.round(realNumber);
// first guess
long guess = scanner.nextLong();
while (guess != realerNumber) {
    System.out.println("Try Again...");
    // guess again
    guess = scanner.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("You Win!");
```

There is already a [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to generate random numbers, you could use it:

```
// TODO: move to constant
int MAX = 10;
// nextInt(int n) generates a number in the range [0, n)
int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(MAX + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to add a little more stuff in the while statements area, but you got me started. I got my final result that I wanted and I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

just put your code inside the **do-while loop**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{
    System.out.println("Please Enter A Number: ");
    double s = scanner.nextDouble();

    double realerNumber = Math.round( Math.random() * 10 );

    System.out.println(realerNumber);

    if(s==realerNumber) {
        System.out.println("You Win!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Try Again...");
    }
}
while(someCondition);
```

the `someCondition` can be for example a counter (if you want to play **n** times just set counter to **n** and decrease it every loop iteration then check if it is 0 in while) or some function checking if a key is pressed (like **escape**)

```
int n = 5;

do
{
    n--;
    ...
}
while(n > 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will run forever, but it's the idea mentioned in the first comment

```
    ...
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){ // add this after Scanner ... declaration
       ...
        } // end of existing else block
    } // end of while loop, so add this single brace
    ...
```

Comment: Why not `while (true)`? :-)

Comment: Are you kidding me? -1? Geez.

Comment: Why NOT `while(1==1)`??

Comment: I didn't -1 you, although your program doesn't exactly do what is requested (it generates new numbers over and over instead of sticking with one. It doesn't **really** matter for this use case, but it should be noted).

Comment: Good point. I didn't think you downvoted me. Heck you SMILED at me! Just trying to give the guy an idea about while loop. But I'm not sure it isn't what he requested. Maybe I didn't read into his request.

Comment: As for *Why NOT `while(1==1)`*, for the same reason that you wouldn't use `while ((1 > 0 && 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 / 2) || 0 != 0)`... It's constantly `true`.